# Why Laravel 5.1 seed's hash is not working for Authentication

Tags: php, hash, laravel-5, seeding

I made a seeder for making a admin user for my app

**My seed class**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        User::create([
        'email'=>'admin',
        'username'=>'admin',
        'password'=>bcrypt('admin'),
        'name'=>'admin',
        'type'=>'a',
        'lastLogin'=>'test',
        'permission'=>'1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1']);

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

it is creating record in my db. But if I use this record for `AuthController` it fails. So tried to create a record using `route.php` Closure like this

```
Route::get('install',function(){


    return \App\User::create([
        'email'=>'admin',
        'username'=>'admin',
        'password'=>bcrypt('admin'),
        'name'=>'admin',
        'type'=>'a',
        'lastLogin'=>'test',
        'permission'=>'1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1']);

});
```

This works very well with `AuthController`. So to figure out the problem I tried to replace seed created record's hash with this hash. Then it works well. How come both `bcrypt()` hash got different even though both uses same random string as salt ?

**Migration for users table**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('username'); 
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->enum('type',['a','m','u']);
            $table->string('lastLogin');
            $table->string('permission');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

**.env file**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=aL3s6hAk375ogGSJQVKVB1r3Jf6OHZ5j

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mymoney
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=vip12340

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

`config\app.php`

```
return [

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),

    'url' => 'http://localhost',

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    'locale' => 'en',

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    // I tried both ways
    // 'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'), 
    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'aL3s6hAk375ogGSJQVKVB1r3Jf6OHZ5j'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    'log' => 'single',

   // All default providers and aliases 

];
```

I used `php artisan serv`  **as web server for all test** and **laravel version 5.1**. Sorry for very long question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-laravel-51-seeds-hash-is-not-working-for-authentication). Instead of making hash our side of the `User` model. We have to use

```
Public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
{ 
         return $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
}
```

in `User` model. I don't know why both hash is different this works well 
So my seed class would be like this

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            Model::unguard();

            // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
            User::create([
            'email'=>'admin',
            'username'=>'admin',
            'password'=>'admin',
            'name'=>'admin',
            'type'=>'a',
            'lastLogin'=>'test',
            'permission'=>'1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1']);

            Model::reguard();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Laravel default Auth system? if it is then you should enter your valid email to make login successful. You can try like this way.

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            Model::unguard();
            $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        }
    }
    class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run() {
            App\User::create( [
                'username' => 'admin'
                'email' => 'admin@gmail.com',
                'password' => Hash::make( 'password' ),
                'name' => 'Admin ',
                'type'=>'a',
                'lastLogin'=>'test',
                'permission'=>'1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1'
            ] );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried using `Hash::make()` still same issue. Email is correct in fact it working well if I replace hash

Comment: you can use bcrypt() or Hash::make() any of this. now what's the problem?

Comment: what is the exact error? are your seeding is successful?

Comment: Yeah seeding is successful, But `Auth` returns false if I use that record. If I update the hash with the hash generated in `route.php` same things works

Comment: have you made any changes in your Auth controller?